# Where is the native code of Ionic Native plugins?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm using the `Ionic` / `Native` plugin: `@ionic-native/camera` for an `Android` device.

On the file: `home.ts`, I have this line at the begining:

```
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
```

My questions are:

- where on the system is located the native code of this plugin?, I mean the java file (compiled or not)
- at what time is the compilation of that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/ tells the camera plugin comes from there: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

And there you have `src/android` directory where all the plugin's java files live.
After installation on the system it is in `plugins/cordova-plugin-camera` under your app's directory.

I think they are compiled together with your app, whenever you trigger the build with `ionic build` or `cordova build` command.